# how to take dump of mysql for federated table?

Tags: mysql, federated-table

now iam using mysql version 5.0.45.and the problm is,i want to take a dump of database. and it contains federated tables also. wen i am taking dump  , it is showing an  error "ERROR 1031 (HY000): Table storage engine for 'employee_details' doesn't have this option"  . actually 'employee_details' table federated from another database. how to solve this problm.? advanced thanks.

Comment: Do you want to restore you database?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this page - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21360

Your dump script may have ALTER TABLE statements, but FEDERATED tables cannot be altered, it is a [restriction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-limitations.html). Try to restore your table without ALTER TABLE statements.